# What are UInt16LE, UInt16BE, etc. in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, integer, buffer

In all of my time programming I have squeaked by without ever learning this stuff. Would love to know more about what these are and how they are used:

- UInt8
- UInt16LE
- UInt16BE
- UInt32LE
- UInt32BE
- Int8
- Int16LE
- Int16BE
- Int32LE
- Int32BE
- FloatLE
- FloatBE
- DoubleLE
- DoubleBE

See https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint8_offset_noassert for where Node uses these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This datatypes are related to number representation in appropriate [byte-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It typically essential for:

- Network protocols
- Binary file formats

It is essential because one system should write integers/floats in such way that will give the same value on reader side. So what format to be used is just convention between two sides (writer and reader).

What acronyms means:

- BE suffix stands for BigEndian
- LE stands for LittleEndian
- Int is Integer
- Uint is Unsigned Integer

Appropriate number in integers is number of bits in the word.